# Simultaneous R sessions within different directories

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rparallel

I am looking in a way to start a new `R` instance working in a user-defined directory from a current `R` session. For example, let's say I have

```
getwd()
##  [1] "/Users/jplecavalier/projects/foo"
```

and I want to do something like

```
start_new_session("bar_session", "/Users/jplecavalier/projects/bar")

set_focus("bar_session")
getwd()
##  [1] "/Users/jplecavalier/projects/bar"

kill_session("bar_session")
getwd()
##  [1] "/Users/jplecavalier/projects/foo"
```

In other words, I want to be able of evaluating something using another `R` session referring to another working directory while keeping the main `R` session waiting. Is there any package/function/way-of-doing-kind-of-this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `callr` package?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!